# A083569: Smallest m not occurring earlier such that m+n is prime

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

Define a 1-indexed sequence as follows:

- `A083569(1) = 1`
- `A083569(n)` where `n` is an integer greater than `1`, is the smallest integer m not occurring earlier such that `m+n` is a prime number.

Your task is to take in `n` and return `A083569(n)`.

```
 n  A083569(n)
 1  1
 2  3
 3  2
 4  7
 5  6
 6  5
 7  4
 8  9
 9  8
10 13
11 12
12 11
13 10
14 15
15 14
16 21
17 20
18 19
19 18
20 17
```

More testcases can be found [here](https://oeis.org/A083569/b083569.txt). The original sequence on OEIS can be found [here](https://oeis.org/A083569).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder "Define a 1-indexed sequence as follows"

Answer (score 15):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>87</s> <s>86</s> <s>83</s> <s>80</s> <s>74</s> 69 bytes

*Thanks to xnor for suggesting some changes that saved 3 bytes!*

```
f n=[m|m<-[1..],all((>0).mod(n+m))[2..n+m-1],all((/=m).f)[1..n-1]]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY6tybXRjfaUE8vVicxJ0dDw85AUy83P0UjTztXUzPaSE8PyNA1hErq2@Zq6qVpgpTnAQVjFRUN/ucmZuZZWXn6a2hygZgKtgq5iQW@8RoFRZl5JVDFRgax/wE)

I'm new to Haskell, and Haskell golfing, feedback is appreciated!

### Explanation

We define a function `f n`.  We define `f n` to be the first element `!!0` of the list:

```
[m|m<-[1..],all((>0).mod(n+m))[2..n+m-1],all((/=m).f)[1..n-1]]
```

Broken down that is:

```
[m|          # Numbers m
m<-[1..],    # From the integers greater than 0
all          # Forall x
(>0).mod(n+m)# n+m mod x is not zero
[2..n+m-1]   # from the integers from 2 to n+m-1
all          # Forall
((/=m).f)    # when f is applied the result is not m
[1..n-1]     # from the integers from 1 to n-1
```

Comment: Welcome to Haskell golfing! The`[2,3..]` can just be `[2..]`, counting up by 1 is default. There's a built-in `notElem`.

Comment: @xnor Thanks! I ended up finding a better way around using `notElem` but the first tip was helpful and I'll make sure to keep that second one in my back pocket.

Comment: Looks like your new revision gets `f 1` wrong, should be 1.

Comment: @xnor Fixed, unfortunately at the cost of 3 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
Rɓ²R+⁸ÆPTḟḢṭµ/Ṫ
```

This assumes **A083569(n) ≤ n²** (the sequence appears to be growing linearly).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//UsmTwrJSK@KBuMOGUFThuJ/huKLhua3CtS/huar/MjBSwrXFvMOH4oKsR/8)

#### How it works

```
Rɓ²R+⁸ÆPTḟḢṭµ/Ṫ  Main link. Argument: n

R                Range; yield [1, ..., n].
 ɓ               Begin a dyadic chain with swapped arguments.
            µ/   Reduce the range by that chain.
                 If we call the chain f, this computes f(2,1), then f(3,f(2,1)),
                 then f(4,f(3,f(2,1)), etc.
                 The left argument is an integer k, the right one an array A.
  ²                Square; yield k².
   R               Range; yield [1, ..., k²].
    +⁸             Add k, yielding [1+k, ..., k²+k].
      ÆP           Test each sum for primality.
        T          Truth; get all indices of 1‘s. This finds all m in [1, ..., k²]
                   such that m+k is prime.
         ḟ         Filterfalse; remove all resulting elements that appear in A.
          Ḣ        Head; extract the first remaining result.
           ṭ       Tack; append the extracted integer to A.
                 This computes the first n elements of the sequence.
              Ṫ  Tail; extract the last, n-th element.
```

Comment: Indeed, `A083569(n)` is at most the `n`th prime larger than `n` by its definition, which is at most the `2n`th prime, which (for `n≥3`) is less than `4n*log(n)` by results of Rosser–Schoenfeld.

Comment: While @GregMartin verified it, it's still a pretty wild assumption to make...

Comment: @Challenger5 I prefer "educated guess".

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth - <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 15 bytes

*Thanks to @isaacg for saving me two bytes!*

Back on this site, after being busy for a while, will hopefully golf this one further.

```
esmaYf&-TYP_+Th
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=esmaYf%26-TYP_%2BTh&input=10&debug=0).

Comment: Welcome back to PPCG!

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks :)

Comment: `-TY` is one byte shorter than `!/YT`, and truthy in the same cases.

Comment: You can save another byte by changing `+hdT` to `+Th`.

Comment: @isaacg, oh does it cast the first element to a list? That's really cool.

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 169 bytes

```cs
n=>{if(n<2)return 1;var p=new int[n-1];int i=0,j,s;for(;i<n-1;)p[i]=f(++i);for(i=1;;i++){for(j=2,s=i+n;j<s&&s%j++>0;);if(j==s&!System.Array.Exists(p,e=>e==i))return i;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVBNT8MwDL3vV5hJTInSTe0QCJS60oTgAkgIDhymHaIuRa66dEqywTT1t5e04mO94INjvzy/PCd307y2uoUQeaWcg2dbv1u1GXXIsc9dOK885bCvaQ1Pigzjv1d/pC5eD87rzex@Z/KUjI8gpAwKQDC7qpIDboGtwexIBTPpnFvtd9ZAIvfKwhaN/uhml2aarGQogDCOysjJorZMUhpwybdLWmHBhCDe44SJlCQEP3ZdifPIIQkjy9RNJu68FCKLJZfhxRLRTc6@3S6sVYfZ3Sc579g20phpROI/lkg2TTu0PtyjtsB6i2HNRIYjRZjHoQhOBsyTH7qtjasrPXuz5PUjGc3Gi/j64vLqho1BBA0BYx70uqZgwYwc/aPyotX6QR/YCavpq6b9Ag)

By far the most inefficient way to calculate the results, so please refrain from calculating `f(n)` for `n>=30` with this code. The first step is to recursively calculate the values from `f(1)` to `f(n-1)` and then proceed to calculate `f(n)` by searching for the first `i` such that `n+i` is prime and `i` is not in the previous values list.

Answer (score 3):

## x86-64 Assembly, <s>57</s> 55 bytes

I'm new to golfing, so comments/feedback are appreciated.

Note: this is optimized for machine code length, not for source length.

```
0: 89 f8 ff cf 74 32 97 89 fe 89 f1 ff c6 89 f0 99
1: f7 f1 85 d2 e0 f7 85 c9 75 ed 89 f9 ff c9 56 29
2: fe 56 57 51 89 fc e8 d3 ff ff ff 59 5f 5e 39 c6
3: e0 ef 96 5e 74 d1 c3
```

Defines a function, using the standard convention (i.e. return value in eax, first argument in edi, all registers caller-saved except ebx) that takes an unsigned 32-bit integer and returns the smallest m etc.

Source:

```assembly
    .globl a083569
    // edi = original, probably don't touch
    // esi = candidate prime, if it's not a repeat we return edi-this
a083569:
    mov %edi, %eax
    dec %edi
    jz end
    xchg %eax, %edi
    mov %edi, %esi
primecheck:
    mov %esi, %ecx
    inc %esi
primeloop:
    mov %esi, %eax
    cdq
    div %ecx
    test %edx, %edx
    loopnz primeloop
/* end */
    // if esi isn't prime, then ecx is now one or greater.
    test %ecx, %ecx
    jnz primecheck
    // esi is now our target prime: check if it's not already one
    mov %edi, %ecx
    dec %ecx
    push %rsi   /* we need a flag-safe way to restore this later */
    sub %edi, %esi
chkdup:
    push %rsi
    push %rdi
    push %rcx
    mov %ecx, %edi
    call a083569
    pop %rcx
    pop %rdi
    pop %rsi
    cmp %eax, %esi
    loopne chkdup
/* end loop - chkdup */
    xchg %esi, %eax
    pop %rsi
    je primecheck
/* end outer loop - primecheck */
end:
    ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVTbUtswEH22vmKHaYYEcoG2MG0oT7zyCZ1hFEm2FWzJSDJxYPj1pruy7CR@8Eir1Tm756zNvVf1ptovCiEOh@Xz082aZUsfnDZFdjGRMJF/zQXDWFHZTQX85tePu/vfLFutQEkNj2CdLrTh1RwaZzccsUBacxkg2FaUfaKnRMGN1JIHhYm6VnPQOehw6cHYABycahQPsFO4Cq0zBL8IpfYscWJhtX2HCcbn@OYdy6QScc@y7QcoI1nWibKIh/N0cHrFaxapRanEK8JpI/poyvIxS4zAuIr5lbXN@jyJ2IV8w0z9nu4E5QNR9dQYoGvmA0YItrqiIuFqFVXB9kkY7UmsJEkoFTYuOoyiLDuwRqHAUDiURrnlSCK6odLtwBCbGuUe7rcOAneFSgxriGnn0leILvfEdS7XmRBZ0/oSJs7rDNtAl4xSEm3LK14sPM8V7PgePUf3fLBOAVkHFZUdG/bt5tQHUb7KlkQdYcelPC6Jt69IjIYKXp2MYWOblNev4uW4IkRRN@Mw0D46oqAnH@ygICxSMNaahujo9BFxq07VTgi2pS4TzvGYsPAYm8SJZpTM22BrHjT1sIdCGeVQIAm5szV5D7mtKrvDbw@eQFip1oypDsENtMbrwpDkfevTITB7YEybADXXZjr7ZIAP7fVDXOY4PlP9ePsA@s/tHb6vr2fwiS3hFx7y6fiJ4@c4H7H1bNbf/mJfjGEbkJ70FyAuRq9k4Fs2cZveqyr7dkuy4Xb5/H2dYrQ/NTAbDTw/7sYAHye8B6Vf02BjZ90xhZ/zEgOX8qSMnvDlpe/4BX2Og0EZd0PK1qgMy41OD82QaYfDP0ET7g@L@v7nfw)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <strike>194</strike> <strike>170</strike> 110 bytes

*84 bytes saved by Leaky Nun*

*2 bytes saved by mathmandan*

```
def s(n):
 a=[s(j)for j in range(1,n)];i=1
 while(i in a)|any((i+n)%j<1for j in range(2,i+n)):i+=1
 return i
```

Defines a function s(n) that takes a number as input and returns A083569(n).

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##XY4xCsJAEEX7nGIaYYakGe1WcxKxWHBjZpGfsFmRgHdfmU6s33@Pv@51XnBq7Z4m2hgSOorjdeMs01Iok4FKxCOxDpDb2Ubt6D3bM7E5i/KJ2JmthxzyRf@k4@BAgvXulVRfBWTNV/hNq0pYi6Gyf5D2BQ)

Comment: You might consider including [this TIO link](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsMgDIbvPkUuA6WX2N1K8zazNDJSUcfY0zu1jvWSn/x8fEn45P2QeykPt0HQYhYFTLOC985PB7xKLYA3kBsT4RJdfkUB28qJaowCVROkIaj4Ol9YJvwbLRyxnuKps0MDvs@T8efV5knaGyLu6w9tMLb01w@4hMiSddIWjSlf).

Comment: You can use `p=lambda n:any(n%i<1for i in range(2,n))` for the primality check.

Comment: [110 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY4xDsIwEAT7vOIapDslzUFnyEsQhSUcchbaRBcjlNcb3CHqmVntupd5wanWe5poY0joKI7XjbNMi1MmA3nEI7EOkNvZRu3oPdszkTUW6WtF7MzWQw75on/ZcWhAgvWt9FReDrLaLPyOq0pY3VC4vZD6AQ)

Comment: You can use  bitwise or to save a couple bytes: `while(i in a)|any(...`

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, <s>158</s> 155 bytes

```
#(loop[r[0 1]i 1](if(= i %)(last r)(recur(conj r(nth(for[j(range):when(=((set r)j)(seq(for[k(range 2(+ 1 i j)):when(=(mod(+ 1 i j)k)0)]j)))]j)0))(inc i))))
```

This might still have some fat, I'm not quite happy with `(+ 1 i j)` but this was the easiest way to handle base case `n = 1` and the rest. `((set r)j)` returns `nil` if `j` is not in the set, and `(seq ())` on an empty list returns nil as well. Calculates `n = 1000` in 48 seconds.

Update: removed `nil` from `=` check as the code works correctly also without it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 62+8 = 70 bytes

Uses the `-rprime` flag.

```ruby
f=->n,o=[]{o<<f[n-1,o]if n>1;Prime.find{|i|i>n&&o|[i-n]!=o}-n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrLCoJQFEbh@f8UOysp8Ehby676DM1FpNJTG@yc8EJE9uxWk/VNVt2dX8N4VP8gVT9quZeDjlViPBun2dseDjo1ij2biSaT8P74X3wtpnj30ktiXNf2qSiTjWL7UeYzPG9SlXQt2wYkFNMk91ubC@jRtQ0506DY0S8OTSkVj7R/OVXVTOYZSlMMjAAhllghwhobbMELMIMDcAheglfgCLwGb8BbBIsv)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 16 bytes

```
!¡λḟȯṗ+→L¹`-N);1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9odXNr/23igoHhuKMxMDD/IcKhzrvhuJ/Ir@G5lyvihpJMwrlgLU4pOzH//w)

1-indexed.